# Which Spring Annotation use with the messageArrived from MQTTCallBack

Tags: java, spring, annotations, mqtt, subscribe

I'm new to Spring, and I'm trying to insert data into my MySQL from the information received by MQTT.

I created my application with the following code.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(MqttServiceApplication.class, args);
        context.registerShutdownHook();

        ProductionSubscribe();
    }
```

With the method

```
    public static void ProductionSubscribe() {
        try {
            IMqttClient client = new MqttClient("tcp://192.168.0.201:1883", new Date().getTime() + "");
            client.connect();

            ProductionCallBack productionCallBack = new ProductionCallBack();
            client.setCallback(productionCallBack);

            client.subscribe("/InputCounter/#");
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

So, I implemented MqttCallback

```
@Component
public class ProductionCallBack implements MqttCallback {

    @Autowired
    private MachineService machineService;

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {
        System.out.println(throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String s, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
        String name = s.replace("/InputCounter/", "").split("/")[0];
        Date now = new Date();

        EasyIOModel easyIOModel = new ObjectMapper().readValue(mqttMessage.toString(), EasyIOModel.class);

        // Get Machine
        Machine machine = machineService.getMachineByNameAndInputNumber(easyIOName);
        if (machine == null) {
            System.out.println("Error.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {
        System.out.println("deliveryComplete");
    }
}
```

Everything is going well until call the method messageArrived.
My service machineService is null, and dont can call services

If I use REST controllers, my services works well... But I don't know which annotations to use in this case with MQTT, so I can call my services.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implement CommandLineRunner in principal class.
Result:

```
public class MqttServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements AsyncConfigurer, CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    ProductionCallBack productionCallBack;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        ProductionSubscribe();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a @Component for custom implementation for MqttCallback like below.

```
@Component
@Log4j2
public class CustomMqttCallbackImpl implements MqttCallback {

    @Autowired
    private ParsingService parsingService;

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
        log.info("Client disconnected: " + cause.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
        parsingService.parseMessage(topic, mqttMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {
        log.info("deliveryComplete");
    }

}
```

Also you can assign this callback object to MqttClient like this.

```
@Log4j2
@Configuration
public class MqttClientConfig {
@Autowired
    CustomMqttCallbackImpl customMqttCallbackImpl;

    @Bean
    IMqttClient getMqttClient() throws MqttSecurityException, MqttException {
        log.info("getMqttClient called");
        // MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();
        MqttDefaultFilePersistence persistence = new MqttDefaultFilePersistence("/temp");
        IMqttClient mqttClient = new MqttClient(MQTT_SERVER_URL, clientId, persistence);

        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
        options.setCleanSession(true);
        options.setConnectionTimeout(10);
        options.setUserName(MQTT_USERNAME);
        options.setPassword(MQTT_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        mqttClient.setCallback(customMqttCallbackImpl);
        
        mqttClient.connect(options);
        return mqttClient;
    }

}
```